# Why is ls much slower than echo *?

Tags: ls, time, echo

(Inspired by the comments for [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead))

Why is `ls` this much slower than `echo *`?

```
$ time bash -c 'for i in {1..10000}; do ls -f > /dev/null; done'
bash -c 'for i in {1..10000}; do ls -f > /dev/null; done' 7.49s user 5.39s system 108% cpu 11.883 total
```

```
$ time bash -c 'for i in {1..10000}; do echo * > /dev/null; done'
bash -c 'for i in {1..10000}; do echo * > /dev/null; done' 0.16s user 0.25s system 98% cpu 0.415 total
```

I mean, sure, `ls` being slightly slower than `echo *` makes sense, but this seems ridiculous.

Why would `ls` be nearly  be the case?

If it has to do with `ls` not needing the speed, then there's no reason for `yes` [to be so fast](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/199528/fastest-yes-in-the-west).

What is `ls` doing under the hood that makes it so slow?

(I'm using zsh on Arch Linux, on a laptop. Times are similar on bash. I've also tested on a (Linux Mint) desktop computer with similar results. (There, `ls -f` is faster at around 7 seconds, `echo *` is still about 0.4 seconds, which is still a ridiculous difference.) On Arch Linux, `ls` was also unaliased, but I didn't bother for Mint, and it didn't make a difference anyway.)

Comment: If you replace ls with /bin/ls and echo with /bin/echo in your tests, is there still a large difference?

Comment: A follow up to @MarkPlotnick point, your `echo` is probably using the shell's built-in while `ls` is forking a new process each time.  Changing `echo` to `/bin/echo` will cause the script to `fork` and `exec` that program.  That'll give you more of an apples-to-apples comparison.

Comment: @muru Fixed, sorry

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Looks like that made a difference.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Not too sure what the convention is, do you want to add that as an answer or should I answer it myself and accept it?

Comment: @muru I used single quotes?

Comment: Also for comparison, try using something like busybox, where both `echo` and `ls` are essentially builtins

Comment: @FaeFeyFa you didn't use any quotes in the post. Andy added those.

Comment: @muru Yup, I've marked as duplicate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `strace`, we can see `echo` makes far less syscalls to the kernel compared to `ls`:

```
root@4a21b0630cba:/# strace -c ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib32  lib64  libx32  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
  0.00    0.000000           0         7           read
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           write
  0.00    0.000000           0        10           close
  0.00    0.000000           0         9           fstat
  0.00    0.000000           0        26           mmap
  0.00    0.000000           0         9           mprotect
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           munmap
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           brk
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           rt_sigaction
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           ioctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         8           pread64
  0.00    0.000000           0         2         2 access
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           execve
  0.00    0.000000           0         2         2 statfs
  0.00    0.000000           0         2         1 arch_prctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           getdents64
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_tid_address
  0.00    0.000000           0         8           openat
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_robust_list
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           prlimit64
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000000                    99         5 total
root@4a21b0630cba:/# 
root@4a21b0630cba:/# 
root@4a21b0630cba:/# 
root@4a21b0630cba:/# strace -c echo *
bin boot dev etc home lib lib32 lib64 libx32 media mnt opt proc root run sbin srv sys tmp usr var
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           read
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           write
  0.00    0.000000           0         4           close
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           fstat
  0.00    0.000000           0         7           mmap
  0.00    0.000000           0         4           mprotect
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           munmap
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           brk
  0.00    0.000000           0         6           pread64
  0.00    0.000000           0         1         1 access
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           execve
  0.00    0.000000           0         2         1 arch_prctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           openat
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000000                    36         2 total
root@4a21b0630cba:/#
```